# Reactive Form - Input field focus out automatically - Angular

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-reactive-forms

I am having strange issue. [**Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2xdwud)

**.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      'options': this.formBuilder.array([this.createOption()])
    });

  }

  createOption(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      'name': [null]
    });
  }
}
```

**.html**

```
<form novalidate [formGroup]="myForm" >
    <div formArrayName="options" class="mt-3">
          <div [formGroupName]="i" *ngFor="let option of myForm.get('options').value; let i = index;">
<input id="{{'name' + i}}" autocomplete="off" type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Name"
                    formControlName="name">
          </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I have a form which has multiple options' `name` field. In html I have loop for each options to show fields. Now if I enter any character in the input field, it automatically focus out of the field.

If I change `*ngFor="let option of myForm.get('options').value; let i = index;"` to `*ngFor="let option of myForm.get('options').controls; let i = index;"` - it solves the issue.

But if I try to deploy it on production and I run

`ng build --prod`

It gives error `Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.`

Need help on this.

Comment: It isn't a strange issue, it has been widely reported (and it's not even an issue). [Here is a github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/13327) that might help you. In two words, you should create a [custom trackby function](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#change-propagation).

Comment: @trichetriche, _I think it's because the *ngFor is over  myForm.get('options'). **value** . MUST be over  myForm.get('options'). **controls**. to avoid the error in AbstractControls, create a getter of the array: get options(){ return this.myForm.get('options').controls as FormArray}

Comment: @Eliseo this is another issue : I'm not saying you're wrong, I'm just saying that losing focus on an input after a keystrike is the result of the trackby function of the loop. But definitely an error to correct too !

Comment: @Eliseo can you come up with stackblitz.com ? I am unable to create `get options()`, it gives error on `.controls` .

Comment: your forked stacbltiz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gjquxc?file=src/app/app.component.ts. Sorry it was only this.myForm.get('options') as FormArray and *ngFor="let option of options.controls". I have not Angular here, but I think that you can build it

Comment: @Eliseo this worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looping over `myForm.get('options').value` you shuold loop over `myForm.get('options').controls`

This should do the trick:

`<form novalidate [formGroup]="myForm" >
    <div formArrayName="options" class="mt-3">
        <div [formGroupName]="i" *ngFor="let option of myForm.get('options').controls; let i = index;">
             <input id="{{'name' + i}}" autocomplete="off" type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Name" formControlName="name">
        </div>
   </div>
</form>`