# onBlur fires on every keystroke instead of on just losing focus on the control

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have an Angular form here

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-array-duplicate-validation

And I have two issues with it.

- The isNameDuplicate validator is being called for every keystroke
  whereas I want it to be fired only on Blur.
- If I enter John in the firstusername and then click on the add button
  and I again enter John and later correct it to Jose.       I get an
  error in the console

  **Error:**

> ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError:  Expression has changed
>   after it was checked. Previous value: 'ng-valid: false'. Current
>   value: 'ng-valid: true'

How do i avoid both the errors ?

Any ideas how i avoid these issues.

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Comment: Apologies i have now fixed the link which should show the code

Comment: For some reason your focus is getting lost from the input after each krystroke , thats why the validation is taking place again and again.

Comment: Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54008466/reactive-form-input-field-focus-out-automatically-angular   and Change your ngFor to  *ngFor="let creds of form.get('credentials').controls;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **trackBy**

> The trackBy function takes the index and the current item as
>   arguments and needs to return the unique identifier for this item

**component.html**

```
<div formArrayName="credentials" *ngFor="let creds of form.controls.credentials?.value; let i = index;trackBy: cmpare;">
          <ng-container [formGroupName]="i">
            <input placeholder="Username" formControlName="username">
            <input placeholder="Password" formControlName="password">
          </ng-container>
 </div>
```

**component.ts**

```
cmpare(index) {
    return index;
}
```

Forked Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-array-duplicate-validation-8mojks

Answer (score 1):

You have iterated through `value` of each `FormControl` of `FormArray`. So when the value of that control changes it generates whole new object and that's why it generates a new textbox having some value in it. And it seems that textbox got blurred, but actually it is new textbox.

You should iterate on controls of array instead of its value.

**Updated code: HTML**

```
    <div formArrayName="credentials" *ngFor="let creds of form.controls.credentials?.controls; let i = index">
      <div [formGroupName]="i">
      {{form.controls.credentials.controls[i].value | json}} 
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" formControlName="username">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Password" formControlName="password">
      </div>
    </div>
```